# Order by two fields with Low Search

Tags: low-search, filter, orderby

Is it possible to order search results by two fields? I have two price fields - `price` & `sale_price` and ideally need to order by both fields. Can this be done using the custom filters?

```
{exp:low_search:filters query='{segment_3}' result_page='products/results'}
    <select name="orderby_sort">
        <option value="">
            Order by
        </option>
        <option value="{low_search:url orderby_sort='price|asc'}"{if '{low_search_orderby_sort}' == 'price|asc'} selected{/if}>
            Price (Low to High)
        </option>
        <option value="{low_search:url orderby_sort='price|desc'}"{if '{low_search_orderby_sort}' == 'price|desc'} selected{/if}>
            Price (High to Low)
        </option>
    </select>
{/exp:low_search:filters}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by using separate `orderby` and `sort` parameters, eg:

```
{low_search:url orderby="foo|bar" sort="asc|desc"}
```